# How can function known what to return

Tags: python, opencv

My code is down below. This codewill show the image and click and it'll show position. The question is I don't understand
how the function know that x , y will return the position of image

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image/tree.jpg")

def clickPosition(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        text = str(x)+","+str(y)
        cv2.putText(img,text,(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,255),cv2.LINE_4)
        cv2.imshow("Output",img)

#showimage
cv2.imshow("Output",img)
#workwithmouse Mouse
cv2.setMouseCallback("Output",clickPosition)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Maybe you could try rephrasing the  question

Comment: When the user clicks a pixel in the "Output" window, the callback function is called with x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's how `setMouseCallback` is defined. See its [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga89e7806b0a616f6f1d502bd8c183ad3e):

> ```
> void cv::setMouseCallback ( const String & winname,
>                             MouseCallback onMouse,
>                             void * userdata = 0 
>                           )
> ```

This is for C++, not Python, but it's useful to learn how to interpret this, because there's no comprehensive Python-specific OpenCV reference (as far as I know).

The `MouseCallback` type is defined as follows:

> ```
> typedef void(* cv::MouseCallback) (int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *userdata)
> ```
>
> Callback function for mouse events. see `cv::setMouseCallback`.
>
> Parameters
> `event`   one of the cv::MouseEventTypes constants.
> `x`   The x-coordinate of the mouse event.
> `y`   The y-coordinate of the mouse event.
> `flags`   one of the cv::MouseEventFlags constants.
> `userdata`    The optional parameter.

So this defines the signature that is used when calling your mouse callback: first argument is the `event`, then come `x` and `y`, then `flags`. The last argument, `userdata`, is simply a copy of the `userdata` argument passed to `setMouseCallback`, which you can use for your own purposes.